# How to get custom data from android firebase notification?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to implement firebase notifications. But I have trouble finding any documentation on how to retrieve custom data from firebase notification.

[image: Firebase console]

But in in code how to get the custom key.

[image]

I'm using `FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived` to get the message data.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can check your custom data using:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : remoteMessage.getData().entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
    Log.d(TAG, "key, " + key + " value " + value);
}
```

To get specific key:

```
String value = remoteMessage.getData().get("<YOUR_KEY>");
```

Comment: i am using firebase in react native android , where should i mention this for loop.... in MyFirebaseMessagingService.java ? @Chintan Soni

Comment: Yes. You have to put is in **MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**.

Comment: Does this code should to be inserted within onMessageReceived method? Because it doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

Let A be your key, then you can easily parse this value by using the following code.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
    Iterator itr = json.keys();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) itr.next();
           if (key.equals("A")) {
                flag = json.getString(key);
           }
           Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + json.getString(key));
    }
```