# Firebase custom data if App is Closed

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I have used this [How to get custom data from android firebase notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526126/how-to-get-custom-data-from-android-firebase-notification) solution for getting custom data from `Firebase` and it work only if `Application` is open, when `Application` is closed the custom data return empty `String` **`""`**

Another question related if remove the code for `notification` from:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
```

and `application` is closed i recevived always a `notification` but if open not?

I think if `Application` is open use my code but if closed what code use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback `onMessageReceived` is only called when the application is running ie its in foreground.

according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

> onMessageReceived is provided for most message types, with the following exceptions:
>
> - Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background.
>
> In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.
>
> - Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and
>     foreground:
>
> In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

So the payload data you need to fetch using `intent.getExtras()`